# Apache 403 on windows using AliasMatch and -D

Tags: windows, apache, http-status-code-403, portability

After i packaged apache to be portable (used any where), I had the surprise to get 403 error on AliasMatch but not on regular Location resources.

**Update**: I found the fix. Check answer.

Answer (score 0):

And so, here is my own response.

I check the error.log and saw the path of the aliasmatch was wrong ( what a scoop). But note this path is made using a variable. Actually, all the character / that we can expect have been removed.

I look to the origin of the variable but not at the beginning, because all URI based on Location was working. Amazing ! But , the fact is, Location directive seems to convert the ugly \ windows in / to work, but not the AliasMatch  directive. I forget to tell that i launched Apache using command line httpd with option -D and ... an ugly windows path with \ and not /. So, i convert the path in a pretty unix path and all is back in order.

In dos command : SET APACHE_ROOT="%THE_WINDOWS_PATH:\=/%"